# Galois conjugates of Hecke characters

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F$ be a totally real field. Let $K/F$ be a CM quadratic extension with CM type $\Sigma$. Let $E$ be the reflex field of $(K,\Sigma)$. For a Hecke character $\lambda$ over $K$ and $\sigma \in G_{E}$, note that the infinity type of the conjugate $\lambda^{\sigma}$ is the same as that of $\lambda$. In particular, $\lambda^{\sigma}/\lambda$ is a finite order Hecke character over $K$. Here $G_{E}$ denotes the absolute Galois group over $E$. We consider variation over varying CM quadratic extensions of the fixed totally real field.

For a positive integer $m$, can $\lambda$ be chosen to be unramified outside a given non-empty finite set of primes with infinity type $m\Sigma$ so that the order of $\lambda^{\sigma}/\lambda$ is bounded as $K$ varies?

Comment: I can't make head nor tail of this question at this point. What order are the quantifiers in? If you change K then you change sigma and you change lambda because their very definition depends on K, right? Presumably the answer is _not_ "let lambda be the trivial character" but at this point I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Yes, $(K,\lambda,\sigma)$ are varying and $(F,m)$ is fixed. As $\lambda$ has infinity type $m\Sigma$ for $m>0$, it cannot be taken to be the trivial character.

Comment: Can you remind me what the infinity type of a Hecke character is? And I'd really like to know what order the quantifiers are in. Is it "For all $m$ there is a bound $B$ such that for all $K$ and for all $\Sigma$ and for all $\sigma$ there is a character $\lambda$ such that $\sigma(\lambda)/\lambda$ has order at most $B$"? Or is it something close to this but different? (e.g. $\lambda$ before $\sigma$?) I don't want to put words in your mouth! Oh! You want $\lambda$ to actually be $z\mapsto z^m$ at an infinite place in $\Sigma$? Have I got the quantifiers in the right order?

Comment: I still can't make head or tail of your question. Surely for a general $F$ and $m$ there might exist one $K$ and $m$ and $\Sigma$ such that there is no unramified $\lambda$ at all with infinity type $m\Sigma$, because global units screw you up. In particular the answer to the question I ask above is "no, because there might not be any $\lambda$ at all".  I think I will give up on this question because I don't want to sink any time into a question where I don't even understand the order of the quantifiers.

Comment: The positive integer $m$ is fixed and $\lambda$ is now allowed to be unramified outside given non-empty finite set of primes. As we vary over the CM quadratic extensions of $F$, the existence of $\lambda$ is well known and can be found in articles of Rohrlich from early 80's.

Comment: You've changed the question and now allow $\lambda$ so be unramified outside a given finite set of primes (of $K$ presumably?) so now I'm even more confused about what order the quantifiers are in :-) The answer to one interpretation of the question is still "no, because the given set of primes might be empty and in this case there might not exist any $\lambda$ at all, let alone one such that $\sigma(\lambda)/\lambda$ has some property". Oh you've changed the question again :-/ I give in. I'm going to bed. Can you just explain what order the quantifiers go in?